# Why am I experiencing Reputation issues?

Tags: support, reputation

I am sure that an upvote on a question is worth +5 reputation.

Now what I want to talk about here is the fact that earlier today, I gained +5 reputation from my question:

[How do film producers and crews film movies based on entire or just a proportion of towns and cities (real cities and towns)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80662/how-do-film-producers-and-crews-film-movies-based-on-entire-or-just-a-proportion)

It did in fact give me +5 reputation and it gave me that no problem.

What I am confused about is that, only about a minute ago I suddenly got +8 reputation from the ***SAME*** question, though no upvotes or downvotes has happened to the question recently after the question's upvote.

It did give me a reputation boost to 2,458 but I don't know why the site gave me an additional 8 reputation just out of nowhere.

Now to look at my profile, earlier I got +5 from the question mentioned above:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/43257/natural

And from the supposed +8 reputation, it has had no affect on the '*reputation gained since your last visit to the reputation tab*' and it still sits at +5 reputation.

***Why did this happen***?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question actually had an additional **two** upvotes (+10) and two **downvotes** (-4) [at the time of writing].

[image]

So the positive score (1) remains apparently the same but isn't *just* (+1) it's *actually* (+3/-2) which is a **net** +1.

This would be the difference you are seeing. Probably 2 upvotes and a downvote for a net +8 rep gain.

You can always visit your reputation audit at https://movies.stackexchange.com/reputation

Or for more detail on your profile page - https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/43257/natural?tab=reputation